# Show a "view all" categories link in Magento Topmenu

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento main menu dropdown with child sub-categories.

Trying to achieve this result:

```
-Home     - Link1      - Link2     - Link3     - Link4
         |
         |_SubCategory Link
            |_SubCategory Child 1
            |_SubCategory Child 2
         |_**View all Categories within Link1**
```

I've got the dropdown working and I'm also displaying the "view all categories" link at the end of each dropdown (had to edit the "/app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php" file with code below)

```
$html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
    . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';

if ($child->hasChildren()) {
    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
    }

    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
    $html .= '<div class="categoryText">Categories</div>';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" class="viewAllLink"><span>View All</span></a>';
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

I'd like for the "view all" link to lead to a page with an unordered list of all categories within the main category (Link1). Currently the "view all" link only leads to the main category page (which has a landing page with a static block), I can't figure out how to get it to show what I want. I've looked for a while now.

Any tips? Thanks alot!

Comment: Anyone with at least a bit of information would help me greatly!

Comment: Here is an example of what I'd like to create [example link](http://www.vitaminworld.com/categories?left&icid=LeftNav-_-cat-link-_-view-all-bottom-link)

Comment: You can try the following solution;
Create a new module with a controller and layout. You copy the html_topmenu block to the main_content area and apply custom styling to that section. That's the most simple solution and is costing less time than other solutions.